# I am Listening on 127.0.0.1:21 but nothing is showing up. I am following the book Black Hat Python. Should I send something in order to listen?

Tags: python, proxy

[image: snapshot of terminal]

my proxy was copied from the book and it is right.

Here is my proxy code. https://github.com/AllGloryToTheHypnotoad/Black-Hat-Python/blob/master/BHP-Code/Chapter2/proxy.py

Comment: Is there a client connecting to it?

Comment: How do I know? or how should I connect a client? I created a tcp server and client. also udp client. Also Netcat

Comment: Yes, you should connect a client. If you're bound to 127.0.0.1, you might not be able to receive connection requests from the network. Set your browser to ftp : //127.0.0.1/ (without spaces)

Comment: I created all the codes the same as in the link > chapter2. will that be enough to connect a client? I am new to hacking

Comment: @alfadog67 how can I set my browser to ftp ://127.0.0.1/. I am running kali Linux in a virtual machine

Comment: You put the location in your browser's address bar. Normally where you see http(colon slash slash)www.stackoverflow.com, instead put ftp(colon slash slash)127.0.0.1/